# Spark 2.0 with Play! 2.5

Tags: apache-spark, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.5, apache-spark-2.0

I'm trying to use Spark 2.0 with Play! 2.5 but I don't manage to make it work properly (and it seems that there is no example on Github).

I don't have any compilation error, but I have some strange executions errors.
For instance:
Almost all operations on a `Dataset` or a `Dataframe` leads to a `NullPointerException`:

```
val ds: Dataset[Event] = df.as[Event]
println(ds.count()) //Works well and prints the good results
ds.collect() // --> NullPointerException
```

`ds.show` also leads to a `NullPointerException`.

So there is a big problem somewhere that I'm missing so I think that it comes from incompatible versions. Here is the relevant part of my `build.sbt`:

```
object Version {
  val scala            = "2.11.8"
  val spark            = "2.0.0"
  val postgreSQL       = "9.4.1211.jre7"
}

object Library {
  val sparkSQL          = "org.apache.spark"            %% "spark-sql"          % Version.spark
  val sparkMLLib        = "org.apache.spark"            %% "spark-mllib"        % Version.spark
  val sparkCore         = "org.apache.spark"            %% "spark-core"         % Version.spark
  val postgreSQL        = "org.postgresql"              %  "postgresql"         % Version.postgreSQL
}

object Dependencies {
  import Library._

  val dependencies = Seq(
    sparkSQL,
    sparkMLLib,
    sparkCore,
    postgreSQL)
}

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(scalaVersion := Version.scala)
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)

libraryDependencies ++= Dependencies.dependencies

dependencyOverrides ++= Set(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.7.4",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.7.4"
)
```

Comment: can you please share some more code like in above df is dataframe and and if it is in public git repo can u give its link

Comment: I get my Dataframe like this: `spark.sqlContext.read.jdbc(databaseURL, query, connectionProperties)` were query is a valid SQL query.

Comment: And the git repo: https://github.com/ticketapp/play2.5Spark2.0

Comment: have you try it on spark-shell its working there fine or not? Because I tried it with shell n its works and plss can you show what error u get.

Comment: No I didn't try on Spark-shell but I must do it work directly in the application. The error I get with the Github littel app is: Try to map struct<event_facebook_id:string,name:string> to Tuple1, but failed as the number of fields does not line up

Comment: Is your application from which u create a dataframe its have both the fields and both the fields name are same as case class???

Comment: If its work in spark-shell It will also work in application I think your csv header doesn't contains these field same as in case class because when we create csv its header become schema of dataframe so once check that otherwise give me ur sample csv I give u answer with detailed example :)

Comment: The fields name of my case class are the same as the header name (see in the github repo in data/data.csv and the case class in app/application/Event.scala). The csv file is: event_facebook_id,name
abc,kj
qsdqsd,sqdqkj

Comment: i tried it on shell the collect work your project cant run on my system there is dependency unresolved problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue using spark 2.0.0 with play 2.5.12 java.
The activator seems to include the com.fasterxml.jackson-databind 2.7.8 by default, and it doesn't work with jackson-module-scala.

I cleaned my sbt cache

```
rm -r ~/.ivy2/cache
```

My new build.sbt, which yields a waring while compiling, since spark 2.0.0 is compiled with jackson-module-scala_2.11:2.6.5, but still spark 2 seams to work with jackson-module-scala 2.8.7

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.8.7",
   "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.8.7",
   "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.8.7",
   "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.8.7",
   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0",
   "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.0.0"
)
```

The NullpointerException derived from jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson Version: 2.x.x
please read https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala/issues/233